# Variable in function not passing to outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that checks if image loads fine. When I use alert in function, it returns true, but when I use after the function, it always be false. How can I fix that ?

```
var isInstalled = false;

function checkimg(){

isInstalled = true;

}

alert(isInstalled);
```

.

```
<img id="fire" src="player.png" onload="javascript: checkimg()" \>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the alert(isInstalled); will be called before the function checkimg() is called, so, you can not see the change of variable isInstalled as expected

Comment: How can I see the change of variable isInstalled as expected ?

Comment: At the end of the fucntion is one case, the other case, you can create a timeout.

Comment: setTimeOut(checkIsInstall, 1000);
function checkIsInstall() {
  if (isInstalled) {
    setTimeOut(checkIsInstall, 1000);
  }else {
    alert("Loaded");
  }
}

Comment: Is putting return false; or something at the end of the function make it work ?

Comment: hum, i will talk about my flow, first, you implement all the code as you did, then, instead of [ alert(isInstalled); ] using the setTimeout to interval checking the status of isInstalled variable. after the onload finish, it will call the checkimg() function change the isInstalled to true, that make the next execution of checkIsInstall stop interval an alert "Loaded"

Answer (score 0):

Look, you call alert in the same moment you define isInstalled variable, so alert shows it's value - false. Put alert into the checkimg function and see that it works.

Comment: But I should not do that, my question is how to make it working. Using variable outside the function.

Comment: You can't make it working the way it is done right now. The problem is that alert is called before you function checkimg() even executes.